# googledatastore package: Error when querying on timestamp field with datetime function

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

```
gql_query.query_string = "SELECT * FROM <entity> where `timestamp` <= datetime('2014-06-05 00:00:00')"
gql_query.allow_literal = True
resp = datastore.run_query(req)
results = [entity_result.entity
           for entity_result in resp.batch.entity_result]
```

When I run above query it produces error as follows:

```
ERROR:root:Error while doing datastore operation
ERROR:root:RPCError: runQuery Invalid datetime text (does not match pattern): &quot;2014-06-05 00:00:00&quot;
ERROR:root:HTTPError: 400 Bad Request
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Cloud Datastore GQL](https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/gql) uses [RFC 3339 section 5.6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339#section-5.6) to represent datetime strings. In this case, you would need to use a 'T' between the date and time rather than a space and append a 'Z' to the end of the string:

```
SELECT * FROM <entity> WHERE `timestamp` <= datetime('2014-06-05T00:00:00Z')
```

Full documentation on synthetic literals, including more detailed information about datetime literals, can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/apis/gql/gql_reference#synthetic_literals).

Comment: Thanks. That worked! I was using the same query I used for App Engine API. It worked there.

Comment: Yep, Python/App Engine GQL is slightly different than Cloud Datastore GQL. You can see a summary of the difference here: https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/apis/gql/gql_reference#unsupported_features_and_behavior_differences_from_mysqlpython_gql